# Change opacity of pseudo element with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, opacity, pseudo-element

I have a tooltip which is a pseudo element shown when hovering over an image. It works well, the tooltip animates in and out.

I'd also like to be able to trigger showing the pseudo element tooltip with javascript. I've read many posts about javascript being unable to target pseudo elements as they're not part of the DOM, but then I've seen some posts which can, specifically [this one](https://base16solutions.wordpress.com/2018/10/05/dynamically-change-a-css-pseudo-elements-property-values/) and [this one](https://davidwalsh.name/pseudo-element).

I just need js to change the opacity of the `::before` element, the rest I can do, but I don't even know where to start.

The following is from one of the two links above, it can grab the color of the `::before` element;

```
var color = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.element'),':before').getPropertyValue('color');
```

but I'm looking for something to the effect of:

```
window.setComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.element'),':before').setPropertyValue('opacity',"1.0");
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible to do it via dynamically adding a class and then accessing the pseudo element by css.

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49618941/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif, that post uses jQuery, I am not using jQuery, please don't close this question.

Comment: don't simply read the title, read *all* the duplicate